# How do I shallow clone an instance that does not implement Cloneable?

Tags: java, clone, shallow-clone

My framework handles domain objects of any class. I need to be able to shallow clone such a domain object instance `foo`, as if it implemented `Cloneable` (which it doesn't) and I called `Object.clone()` on it which returns a shallow clone.

Things that do NOT work:

- Force foo's class to implement `Cloneable` and therefor the public method `clone()`.
- Through reflection call foo.clone() (to reach the protected method `Object.clone()`). It throws `CloneNotSupportedException` because `foo`'s class does not implement `Cloneable`.
- Serializing and deserializing foo: I need a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

Limitations:

- `foo`'s class is not know at compile time.
- `foo` might have field that are not exposed as getters/setters.

Note: there are a couple of similar questions, but none seem to focus on a getting a shallow clone.

Comment: Create copy constructor, or use reflection to iterate through all fields and copy them to a new instance

Comment: -1.  You shouldn't try to do this; it's not possible, and in fact it would be a bad thing if it were possible.

Comment: @nos no, clarified the question to reflect that. tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html#cloneBean%28java.lang.Object%29) can clone non-cloneable Beans as long as they have setter/getters. Unfortunately [Orika](http://code.google.com/p/orika/) bean mapper doesn't support mapping of private fields either.

In the end, it may be easier for you to implement it based on reflection on your own (as hoaz is suggesting), since most libraries for bean mapping try to perform deep copies and you seem to have some special requirements (such as the support for copying private fields).

Comment: A colleague also linked [this cloner lib](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/) to me

Answer (score 0):

```
class A{
    private int a;
    private int[] b;


    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public int[] getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(int[] b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static A shallowCopyOf(A instanceOfA){ //performs shallow copy
        A newInstance  = new A();
        newInstance.setA(instanceOfA.getA());
        newInstance.setB(instanceOfA.getB());
        return newInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not compatible with limitation "foo's class is not know at compile time"